# Third-Party Vue Packages with Nuxt.js: Will They Work Together?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm diving into using third-party Vue packages/plugins with Nuxt.js and wondering if they play nice together without much hassle. Do all Vue packages just smoothly fit into Nuxt, or do they often need some tweaking or special handling?

My main worry is that a package built for regular Vue might not work as expected within Nuxt. Take, for instance, an OpenStreetMap plugin – what if it works perfectly fine with Vue but runs into issues within a Nuxt project because it doesn't account for server-side rendering and assumes it's only in a browser environment?

I'm trying to get a clearer picture of any challenges or limitations when using third-party Vue stuff in Nuxt.js. Can someone help clarify if there are things I need to watch out for or adapt to make everything work together seamlessly?

Comment: Always depends on a specific package, the question doesn't make sense in general. From the very meaning of OSM, it shouldn't run on server side. The components that generate a markup that isn't wanted on server side, use browser apis or async side effects without SSR in mind, need to be client-only. The libs that don't properly handle instances, i.e don't use vue app instance to store user-sensitive data,  aren't suited for SSR in general, not just nuxt. A lib that doesn't provide nuxt plugin may require to write one manually, depending on the implementation